# Diferencia entre "Coordenadas en pixeles" y "Coordenadas" en Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

Estoy trabajando en procesamiento de video con JavaScript, voy bien, pero estoy usando un método llamado, canvasCtx.rect(), este recibe estos parámetros.
[image: Parámetros]

Y luego ocupo obtener los datos de ese rectángulo que dibujé con el método de getImageData(), pero este recibe estos parámetros:

[image: Parámetros]

Se ven similares y son casi iguales, pero en las coordenadas "X" y "Y", .rect() recibe las coordenadas y .getImageData() recibe las coordenadas "X" y "Y" también , pero ahora en pixeles, y no sé si es mi percepción pero estoy dibujando los datos en una gráfica y siento que se muestran un poco desfasado, quería saber si en efecto, deben de ser distintos valores o realmente es lo mismo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te explico, la diferencia se puede obtener a través de un buen análisis textual:

La primera imagen nos dice lo siguiente de las coordenadas:

- Parametro x: la coordenada "x" a partir de la esquina superior izquierda del rectángulo.
- Parámetro y: la coordenada "y" a partir de la esquina superior izquierda del rectángulo.

La segunda imagen nos dice lo siguiente de las coordenadas:

- Parámetro x: la coordenada "x" en pixeles a partir de la esquina superior izquierda desde la cual empezar a copiar.
- Parámetro y: la coordenada "y" en pixeles a partir de la esquina superior izquierda desde la cual empezar a copiar.

> **Inciso importante:** Ambos métodos tanto el de `rect()`, como el de `getImageData()` trabajan con la medida pixeles (px), sólo que en la
>   primera imagen no se especifica que se trabaja con pixeles (se asume
>   que el programador lo sabe).

Entonces la diferencia según lo anterior descrito es la siguiente:

El método `rect()` y también el método `getImageData()`, utilizan por defecto el canvas (lienzo), como referencia, y ademas su punto de origen es la esquina superior izquierda.

El método `rect` dibuja un rectángulo a partir de los parámetros x, y, width y height, entonces el rectángulo será dibujado dependiendo de:

- Cuantos pixeles debe desplazarse el "pincel" en x (a partir de donde va a dibujar horizontalmente tomando como referencia la esquina superior izquierda).
- Lo mismo de arriba se aplica al eje vertical (Y).
- El ancho y alto (width y height), darán el tamaño total del area desde ese punto por ejemplo el pixel (4, 5), (4 en x y 5 en y), en el que se dibujará el rectángulo en el canvas.

Ahora, algo similar pasa con la función `getImageData`, la diferencia es que esta función no pinta un rectángulo, sino que extrae la data de los pixeles (colores) que están en esa área en un array para que luego puedas usarla para lo que desees.

Por ejemplo, si dibujaste algo en el canvas a modo de paint y luego quieres guardar el dibujo como imagen puedes usar esta función junto con otros métodos para guardar lo que pintaste en el canvas.

Espero esta información te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, me fue muy útil c: